# External Libraries in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, libraries

I wish to use a few external libraries in a project: libpng and libvorbis. Now, on Linux, I can happily build these and just add a configuration file to scons to allow extra include/lib paths if you want to build them outside of the system include path.

However, MSVS 2010 seems to be a bit pickier:

- I can just add the path of the release versions of these libraries to the VC++ directories on the user property page, but this won't work for static linking (because the debug versions are required to link against the debug configuration).
- I can add the absolute path in the project, but this means that the project isn't portable.
- I can add the libpng directory (for example), and then put `Debug\libpng.lib` in the linker input, but it can't find the symbol. Presumably it assumes it's a relative path due to the `\`.

My current solution is to just copy all my required libraries into the solution directory for the current project; I could even hard-link them there, but this seems stupid.

What can I do to keep my project portable, and reference absolute include/lib paths *per configuration*?

(Being able to deliberately put the paths in the .suo or .user files would be awesome for example.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the relative paths of your libraries, preface them with ".\" to start from the base project directory;

```
".\Lib\Debug\libpng.lib"
```

or "..\" to reference the parent directory.

```
"..\Lib\Debug\libpng.lib"
```

Note that if your libraries are located in the Parent Directory's parent directory, then you can just chain the "..\" references together:

```
"..\..\Lib\Debug\libpng.lib"
```

Comment: I already use relative paths, I want to know how to do absolute paths, without it being on a per-project basis.

Comment: You can set absolute library paths in the Visual Studio Global Settings by navigating to "Tools -> Settings -> Projects & Solutions -> VC++ Directories."

That, as it turns out, is fairly common practice for projects which implement commonly-used SDKs which can be installed to different locations on different computers.  Is that what you're talking about?  If so I'll repost as the answer.

Comment: That was removed with VS2010, it also doesn't allow for per-configuration directories, so still wouldn't work with static linking.